# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities error

Tags: c#, linq

I have a view model which contains a `List<>`. This list is a collection of another model and I'm trying to fill this list while filling an `IEnumerable` of my view model. While doing this I get the error *“Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities”*. The error came to be because of the `Locations = new List<>` part in which I try to fill the list. What I would like to know is how to fill this list the correct way.

Code:

```
IEnumerable<PickListLineViewModel> lineList = dbEntity.PickListLine
    .Where(i => i.PickID == id && i.Status != "C")
    .Select(listline => new PickListLineViewModel
    {
        ArticleName = dbEntity.Item
                        .Where(i => i.ItemId == dbEntity.SalesOrderLine
                                .Where(idb => idb.DocId == listline.BaseDocID &&
                                            idb.DocType.Equals(listline.BaseDocType) &&
                                            idb.LineNum == listline.BaseLineNum)
                                .Select(iid => iid.ItemId)
                                .FirstOrDefault())
                        .Select(p => p.Description)
                        .FirstOrDefault(),
        PickID = listline.PickID,
        BaseDocID = listline.BaseDocID,
        BaseDocType = listline.BaseDocType,
        BaseLineNum = listline.BaseLineNum,
        LineNum = listline.LineNum,
        Quantity = listline.Quantity,
        ReleasedByQty = listline.ReleasedByQty,
        Status = listline.Status,
        PickedQuantity = listline.PickedQuantity,

        Locations = new List<BinLocationItemModel>(dbEntity.BinLocation_Item
                        .Where(t => t.ItemId == dbEntity.SalesOrderLine
                                .Where(idb => idb.DocId == listline.BaseDocID &&
                                            idb.DocType.Equals(listline.BaseDocType) &&
                                            idb.LineNum == listline.BaseLineNum)
                                .Select(iid => iid.ItemId)
                                .FirstOrDefault())
                        .Select(locitem => new BinLocationItemModel
                        {
                            ItemId = locitem.ItemId,
                            Barcode = locitem.BinLocation.Barcode,
                            BinLocationCode = locitem.BinLocation.BinLocationCode,
                            BinLocationId = locitem.BinLocationId,
                            BinLocationItemId = locitem.ItemId,
                            StockAvailable = locitem.StockAvailable
                        }))
                        .ToList(),

        ArticleID = dbEntity.Item
                        .Where(i => i.ItemId == dbEntity.SalesOrderLine
                                .Where(idb => idb.DocId == listline.BaseDocID &&
                                                idb.DocType.Equals(listline.BaseDocType) &&
                                                idb.LineNum == listline.BaseLineNum)
                                .Select(iid => iid.ItemId)
                                .FirstOrDefault())
                        .Select(p => p.ItemCode)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .AsEnumerable();
```

BinLocationItemModel:

```
public class BinLocationItemModel
{
    [Required]
    public int BinLocationItemId { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string BinLocationCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int BinLocationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public decimal? StockAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide `BinLocation_Item` & `BinLocationItemModel` contents? The error said you need a parameterless constructor method for corresponding class to be used in collections.

Comment: The `BinLocation_Item` is a database entity and contains StockAvailable and is linked to an item table and location table.

Comment: Remove `new List...`. Use `ToList`.

Comment: I think `new List<BinLocationItemModel>` is unnecessary when it already initialized. Use `Select(locitem => new BinLocationItemModel { ... }).ToList()` if `Location` is already a list indeed.

Comment: That did the trick @IvanStoev thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your PickListLineViewModel constructor you should initialise your Locations list like below

```
    
     public class PickListLineViewModel
     {
         public PickListLineViewModel()
         {
            Locations = new List<BinLocationItemModel>();
         }
         public List <BinLocationItemModel> Locations { get; set; }
     }

     public class BinLocationItemModel
     {
         ....
     }
```

Then for your linq query you should be able to do the following, you wont need your new list inside the linq:

```
    Locations = dbEntity.BinLocation_Item
                    .Where(t => t.ItemId == dbEntity.SalesOrderLine
                            .Where(idb => idb.DocId == listline.BaseDocID &&
                                 idb.DocType.Equals(listline.BaseDocType) &&
                                        idb.LineNum == listline.BaseLineNum)
                            .Select(iid => iid.ItemId)
                            .FirstOrDefault())
                    .Select(locitem => new BinLocationItemModel
                    {
                        ItemId = locitem.ItemId,
                        Barcode = locitem.BinLocation.Barcode,
                        BinLocationCode = locitem.BinLocation.BinLocationCode,
                        BinLocationId = locitem.BinLocationId,
                        BinLocationItemId = locitem.ItemId,
                        StockAvailable = locitem.StockAvailable
                    })
                    .ToList(),
```